# What is format of websphere MQ messages

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, mq

After checking out mq series docs and white paper I have got the architecture for MQ messages ie Message descriptor (Message header)
Application data (Message body) and its [details here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1001_xiao/1001_xiao.html) 
But I want to know what is the format (xml,binary,text...) in which quemanager of MQ series stores the messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format of the payload is decided by the application, not MQ. You can send messages in whatever format you want. As mentioned in the developersWorks article, MQ has some predefined formats such MQFMT_STRING which means the format of the payload is text. This format is typically used for XML, text message body. [These](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc%2Fq091470_.htm) are the predefined list of message formats.

Comment: request you to please share the knowledge source.

Comment: This link http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/fr13160_.htm explains the format type. MQFMT_NONE means payload format is undefined.